# Greenville County, New Home Electrical Grounding Requirements

Tags: electrical

I have two separate ground rods in the ground for my NEW house.  The BUILDER contractor electrician used 2 separate 1/4" copper ground wires.  By Code, should have he used ONLY 1 contiguous ground wire vs two separate ground wires.  (Greenville County, SC)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Do both ground wires go back to the same breaker panel?

Comment: Do both grounding electrode conductors go into the same box? (meter-main, meter base, main panel)

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than a single panel, such as a 400A (class 320) meter that feeds two adjacent 200A panels, a single grounding electrode conductor needs to connect the two panels to the grounding electrode. Other supplemental electrodes such as an additional ground rod, concrete encased rebar, building steel, water piping, are not required to be connected all to that single conductor that goes to the primary grounding electrode. Supplemental electrodes can be connected by a continuous conductor or irreversible tap connection to the primary grounding electrode conductor, but it is not required to be connected that way.